# How to turn a static CGI-style perl script(xxx.pl) to a dynamic PSGI application?

Tags: perl, cgi, rack, plack, psgi

CGI-style perl scripts are hard to test in this style:

```
def test_it_says_hello_to_a_person
   get '/home.pl', :name => 'Simon'
   assert last_response.body.include?('Simon')
end
```

(Note: the code is in ruby, using `Rack::Test`).

But if I can turn static file to a PSGI application
(A code reference, accept `$env` as parameter, return `[$status, $header, $body]`), things will be easy, and `Plack::Test` will do the rest.

I am reading PSGI specification, generally I can see the route to this. But I still want to know is there any existence wheel to this?

Also, I think `Plack::Test`'s interface is not as beautiful as `Rack::Test`, any Alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to look at [Plack::App::WrapCGI](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack::App::WrapCGI). When you give it a Perl script as an argument, it uses a technique similar to [ModPerl::Registry](https://metacpan.org/module/ModPerl::Registry) to compile your CGI script into a PSGI app. And even if it can't figure out how to do that, it has the ability to emulate a complete CGI environment from a PSGI environment, meaning that it can fork and exec a bona fide CGI script (even one written in another language) and run it under any sort of Plack handler, including Plack::Test.